# Facebook showing wrong tumblr on sharing, 302 redirects to main page

Tags: facebook

I have a problem. I want to share my blog post on facebook http://videoefekt.cz/?p=548 but every time I do that, it only shows tumblr of my homepage....Facebook debugger is showing Canonical URL is videoefekt.cz, but it shouldnt be. I am also getting "The following required properties are missing: og:image, fb:app_id" warning.... Its a wordpress website, I tried to change permalinks, tried to erase facebook cache and I don know what else to try, can anyone help ?

Comment: This is your screw-up, not theirs. That link has this in the HTML: `<meta property="og:url" content="http://videoefekt.cz/" />` which is (correctly) detected as the canonical URL.

Comment: I am seeing this in console :
<meta property="og:url" content="http://videoefekt.cz/?p=548">

Comment: Well, I'm not. https://imgur.com/a/uzkWP

Comment: I also set this
<link rel="canonical" href="http://videoefekt.cz/?p=548">

Comment: Is p=548 unpublished, perhaps?

Comment: What you are seeing is HTML screen from the main page, videoefekt.cz ....it is published and created after I changed permalinks to clear

Comment: The URL `http://videoefekt.cz/?p=548` 302 redirects to `http://videoefekt.cz/` for me. Figure out why that is, because that's probably what's happening to Facebook too.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/v9fAy

this is my HTML if you wanna chceck it, Ill look at the redirect, thanks